# $\int z{P'(z) \over P(z)}dz$ in {$z$ complex / $ |z|=3 $} where $P(z)=z⁵+z⁴-9z²+7$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, residue-calculus, complex-integration

$\int z{P'(z) \over P(z)}dz$

I proved that  $P(z)\neq 0$ for all $z$ outside of the ball of radius 3, so all the poles of $ z{P'(z) \over P(z)}$ are inside the ball. What should I do next? How do I find the residues?

Edit: The zeroes of $P(z)$ are poles of $z{P'(z) \over P(z)}$ of order 1. If $a_1$ is a zeroe of P then $res({P'(z) \over P(z)},a_1)=m_1$ where $m_1$ is the multiplicty of the zeroe in $a_1$. 
Then the integral equals $2 \pi i \sum a_i m_i$.

Edit 2: $\sum a_i m_i$ is minus the coefficient of order 4 of $P(z)$, which is 1, then $\int z{P'(z) \over P(z)}dz = -2 \pi i$

Comment: What sort of singularity does $\dfrac{P'(z)}{P(z)}$ have at zeros of $P$? What is the residue there? Therefore, what is the residue of $z\dfrac{P'(z)}{P(z)}$ at the zeros of $P$?

Comment: Hint: If $a$ is a root of $P(z)$ with multiplicity $m$, the residue of $z\frac{P'(z)}{P(z)}$ at $a$ is $ma$.

Comment: Yes, we can know the value without knowing the $a_i$. Consider the polynomial $$Q(z) = \prod (z -a_i)^{m_i}.$$ What is its relation to $P$, and where does $\sum m_i a_i$ occur in $Q$?

Comment: @CristianDesivo You may want to read this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_principle#Generalized_argument_principle You simply have a rather nice and important generalization of the Argument Principle, with $\;g(z)=z\;$ .

Comment: Almost, you have a sign error, the coefficient of $z^4$ is $-\sum m_i a_i$, so the overall result is $-2\pi i$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$P(z)\neq 0$ for all $z$ outside of the ball of radius 3, so all the poles of $ z{P'(z) \over P(z)}$ are inside the ball. The zeroes of $P(z)$ are poles of $z{P'(z) \over P(z)}$ of order 1. If $a_1$ is a zeroe of P then $res({P'(z) \over P(z)},a_1)=m_1$ where $m_1$ is the multiplicty of the zeroe in $a_1$. 
Then the integral equals $2 \pi i \sum a_i m_i$.

$\sum a_i m_i$ is minus the coefficient of order 4 of $P(z)$, which is 1, then $\int z{P'(z) \over P(z)}dz =- 2 \pi i$